# representing compactified stack as a global quotient

Tags: algebraic-geometry, moduli-space, algebraic-stacks

Let $M$ be a DM stack over a field $k$. Assume I managed to represent it as $[X/G]$ for some scheme $X$ and a group scheme $G$. Does that imply that the DM compactification $\overline{M}$ of $M$ is also a global quotient? If yes, how does one prove that? If no, what are natural counterexamples?

Comment: If you don't get an answer here, this seems like an appropriate question for MathOverflow!

Comment: What do you mean by ``THE" DM compactification? The intro to this paper https://people.kth.se/~dary/tamecompactification20110517.pdf asserts that Edidin proved such a compactification by a global quotient exists, but I don't know if it's the one you have in mind.